# Tukey Graphing Problems in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm having trouble extracting and graphing a Tukey test that I did. I did a fairly basic one on an ANOVA but I only want to plot the *significant* mean differences.
When I use the plain

`Tukey <- TukeyHSD(x=aov.out, 'Species', conf.level=0.95)
plot(Tukey)`

The result is [image]

Is there any way to remove all the insignificant mean levels? When I attempted to, I was forced to turn it into a dataframe, which then could not be plotted in the same way.

```
Tukey <- Tukey[[1]][row_to_keep,]
```

NOTE: No packages were installed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question was migrated from crossValidated because it seemed more programming-oriented than pure statistics. However, answering it would require you to provide a sample toy data wich we can use to replicate your undesired results and test our answers. By providing a _reproducible example_, you're also increasing the chances someone will answer your question. Please notice that it's also relevant to declare wich packages have you loaded before you ran the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never I hope... You can just subset the matrix inside the TukeyHSD object.

```
SigOnly <- Tukey 
SigOnly$species <- SigOnly$species[SigOnly$species[,'p adj'] < .05, ]
plot(SigOnly)
```