# Tukey test only plot significant mean differences

Tags: r, tukey

I tried to use the following code from a previous post: [Tukey Graphing Problems in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838046/tukey-graphing-problems-in-r)

```
SigOnly <- Tukey 
SigOnly$species <- SigOnly$species[SigOnly$species[,'p adj'] < .05, ]
plot(SigOnly)
```

But get the following error when trying to plot:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
>         'x' and 'y' lengths differ

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You were already advised in the previous post to provide a reproducible & minimal example including sample data. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50054387/edit) your post to include those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't provide reproducible code with sample data, here is an example using the `warpbreaks` sample data:

```
fm1 <- aov(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks)
res <- TukeyHSD(fm1, "tension", conf.level = 0.95)

# Filter rows with padj < 0.05
res$tension <- res$tension[res$tension[, 4] < 0.05, ];

# Plot results
plot(res);
```

[image]